# Using Statamic Partial Variables within Entries Tags?

Tags: php, content-management-system, statamic

Trying to use partials in the Statamic CMS to keep some content areas as DRY as possible.

According to the [documentation](http://statamic.com/learn/theming/partials), I can pass variables to a partial like so:

```
{{ theme:partial src="sidebar" my_count="2" }}
```

In my partials/sidebar template, I have the following:

```
{{ my_count }}

{{ entries:listing folder="projects" }}
  I am number {{ my_count }}
{{ /entries:listing }}
```

However, when the page loads, the variable inside the {{ entries:listing }} tag is not parsed.

> 2
>   I am number
>   I am number
>   I am number
>   I am number
>   I am number

Am I missing a step to get {{ my_count }} to output when called inside the entries tag pair?

*NOTE:* My ultimate goal is to pass the variable to a parameter, like so:

```
{{ entries:listing folder="projects" limit="{{ my_count }}" }}
  ...
{{ /entries:listing }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable won't parse inside of the `entries:listing` tag pair, but you **can** use it as a parameter.

This example code works:

### partials/temp.html

```
{{ entries:listing
    folder = "blog"
    limit  = "{ limit }"
}}

  {{ title }}

{{ /entries:listing }}
```

### templates/temp.html

```
{{ theme:partial src="temp" limit="2" }}
```